# request plate number from Tattile camera

Tags: digital-cameras, ethernet

I am using a Tattile camera with ANPR and trying to use it with customized SW following ANPR_DeveloperGuide_E.pdf.

I managed to access all functionality (getting data, setting data, requests including getting images) except getting plate numbers. I am doing

1. Enable Engine
2. Start Trigger
3. Get Check List  (A or B)

and for each command I got positive response and there are no errors but the "Get Check List" command return 0 detected plate numbers.

Using the webinterface one can see that the number plate is clearly visible and centered.

Comment: Does it work with the original firmware? Is there some kind of country selection setting? If so, is it correct? Does the web interface show detection of the plate?

Comment: which guide are you referring to? ... what is your specific question? ... please add the info to your post, not to a comment

Comment: It is the original firmware. And with some commercial software it had work in the past - unfortunately I cannot do a TCP dump anymore with it. 
There is no country selection setting (One can just set time zones.)
The web interface shows detection of plates.

Comment: I am using "ANPR ACCESS ANPR ACCESS HD ethernet programmers guide 2015-10-23 | v4.3".

Comment: just a name of a document is meaningless ... please add a link to the document into your post

Comment: Unfortunately the documents are not on the Tattile web page and because of copyright issues I cannot upload it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is another `StartTrigger` command with the same command code but fix content. There is just `gate_time_in_ms`and `trigger_string`. `trigger_string` is fix 32 bytes long and padding bytes and terminating zero are included in the length.

Then the communication is handled on another port (other than 31000). This can be set in the web interface of the camera (under "TCP message").
The camera is now a client and send this message to the requester (The message is not given by the settings in the web interface):

- image as jpeg: variable length padded to full 4 bytes including some text information (Exif?)
- plate text: 32 bytes,
- site address: 128 bytes
- net trig id: 64 bytes